# XBMC Stream Video

Tags: video-streaming, xbmc

Can XBMC stream video to a web interface that I can access with my mobile phone without the need to buy a slingbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be build in to XBMC from what I could see, but there was this post in their forum talking about streaming to android phones, it should work with any phone that can access the internet.

http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=73096&highlight=streaming+http

The second-to-last post gives you the instructions to stream using vlc.

EDIT: It seems like they are trying to add this directly into the next release, Dharma.